htaccess - Redirect URL ONLY When It Contains A Specific Variable
I have a site with old URLs like this:
They use .cfm files, and have a URL variable in them:
/projects/showreport.cfm?reportid=318
/projects/showreport.cfm?reportid=933
/projects/showreport.cfm?reportid=257

Is it possible to somehow redirect them to new pages I have created like this below?
/projects/showreport_reportid_318.html
/projects/showreport_reportid_933.html
/projects/showreport_reportid_257.html

How would I do that with htaccess?
This .htaccess code is NOT working to successfully redirect:
Redirect 301 "/projects/showreport.cfm?reportid=318" "/projects/showreport_reportid_318.html"

That just creates a 404 error on my server at the original URL (no redirect performed).

This is a web server issue, not a ColdFusion issue. Do you have mod_rewrite installed on your Apache server? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html
